# How to slide to div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use classic

```
<a href="#jump">Jumo</a> .... <div id="jump">some content</div>
```

and with this some javascript code ....

```
if ( ! window.console ) console = { log: function(){} };

$('.single-page-nav').singlePageNav({
            offset: $('.single-page-nav').outerHeight(true),
            filter: ':not(.external)',
            updateHash: true,
            beforeStart: function() {
                console.log('begin scrolling');
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                console.log('done scrolling');
            }
        });
```

But it slide not exactly on the top of the div, but some pixels above ... can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: OK ... forget about it ... I found something ... I try to follow this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Single-Page-Scroll-To-Navigation/  and  http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Single-Page-Scroll-To-Navigation.html